# Is that true if we can always fill the delay slot there is no need for branch prediction?

Tags: mips, cpu, cpu-architecture, branch-prediction

I'm looking at the five stages MIPS pipeline (ID,IF,EXE,MEM,WB) in H&P 3rd ed. and it seems to me that the branch decision is resolved at the stage of ID so that while the branch instruction reaches its EXE stage, the second instruction after the branch can be executed correctly (can be fetched). But this leaves us the problem of possibly still wasting the 1st instruction soon after the branch instruction.

I also encountered the concept of branch delay slot, which means you want to fill the 1st instruction soon after the branch with something useful as well as "harmless" that whether the branch is taken or not the instruction is executed as desired and the 1st instruction after the branch is not wasted.

My question is, first of all, is my above understanding correct? If it's correct, then the problem comes from the concept of branch prediction, which seems to be trying to fill the first instruction with instruction from the predicted place that the program is going to. But if we can always find some instruction to fill the branch delay slot, we would not need the feature of branch prediction, right?

Comment: Related: [How does MIPS I handle branching on the previous ALU instruction without stalling?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56586551) - no, it's not resolved in ID, it's resolved in EX with early forwarding to IF, using the first half vs. second half of a single clock cycle.

Comment: (At least for *conditional* branches, it's resolved in EX.  Unconditional jumps/branches like `j` and `jal` can be resolved in ID, maybe even `jr`.  And if special-cased, `b` pseudo-instructions that use `$0` or something for a relative branch.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the classic MIPS (R2000) pipeline, the branch delay slot makes branch prediction useless as you perceive. (Technically, a design could combine a predictor/indicator of whether the delay slot instruction is a nop with a branch predictor. This would allow the nop to be skipped, modestly improving performance on a correct branch prediction.)

However, processor pipelines are often long and wide enough (and branch condition evaluation sufficiently delayed) that a single delay slot is not sufficient to fill the delay between when the post-branch instruction address is needed and the branch direction and target are known.

For example, a follow-on processor, the MIPS R4000, significantly lengthened the pipeline and as a result could not determine the location of the post-branch instruction early enough. The designers chose to use a simple static predict not-taken strategy.

If one did not care about binary compatibility, one could add more delay slots. However, finding useful instructions to fill such slots increases in difficulty as the number of slots increases. For certain loop-rich code, regularly filling two delay slots might be practical, and I think at least one DSP had two delay slots.

Branch prediction can also be used to decouple fetch from execution so that even if the condition cannot be evaluated (e.g., depending on the result of a high latency operation such as a data cache miss or a division), fetch can continue. Such decoupling could be used to generate instruction cache misses early (hiding some of their latency) and to reduce the impact of variable throughput at different stages (so an earlier stage can continue operating with maximum throughput when a later stage stalls or has reduced throughput and the buffered instructions can then hide later stalls or reduced throughput in the earlier stage).

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that complier may not always find a instruction to fill the delay slot.
What is more, instruction is highly predictable.

Before IF stage, u even not know whether it is branch instruction.( u have to fetch it from instruction memory)

Answer (score 0):

within a mips core like that with zero wait state randomly accessed ram sure.  but depending on how the fetching is implemented and caching behind that, you may still want/need the concept of branch prediction to start those fetches earlier.  the pipeline is just a small part of a bigger system.  system busses are usually not single cycle here is my address I want my data by the end of this cycle, there are address busses and data busses and tags that cross them so you can have multiple transactions in flight at the same time, like a pipeline trying to optimize the bandwidth of the data bus knowing the peripherals and memory on the far side are too slow for that bus.

prediction "could" be used to assist these other features in getting instructions into the pipe faster or more efficiently.

from an academic sense though, the idea of the slot is to give the pipe a cycle to switch gears along another execution path.  It only actually saves you if the incoming end of the pipe can be fed any random thing it wants every clock cycle.  which isnt real world.

another academic solution is the arm one of conditional execution on every instruction, you can construction execution sequences to keep the pipe full and not have to flush or stall... again so long as what feeds the pipe can keep up...arm dumped the conditional instruction idea in the new 64 bit instruction set.  some/newer mips you can disable the branch shadow/delay slot.